# How to handle 'Value cannot be null or empty' when using @Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

This is my first time attempting an MVC app.

I'm displaying a grid of data, for which some fields are nullable. Each column has an actionlink allowing the user to filter the page on that data.  Unfortunatly, I cannot figure out how to handle the 'Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: linkText ' error that occurs when I have a field that is null.

The DisplayFormat appears to be ignored for an actionlink?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "'{0}'", NullDisplayText = "'Unknown Initials'")]

public string initials { get; set; }

@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
<td>
   @Html.ActionLink(item.Name.initials, "Index", new { i = item.Name.initials })
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "'{0}'", NullDisplayText = "'Unknown Initials'")]

        public string initials { get; set; }

        @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <tr>

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name.initials)
    {
    <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Unknown Initials", "Index", new { i = "Unknown Initials" })
        </td>
    }
    else
    {
    <td>
           @Html.ActionLink(item.Name.initials, "Index", new { i = item.Name.initials })
        </td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

Comment: That did the trick.

For the record, the above example is just missing the first '@' before the if
                                    }

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `initials` property is null or empty which is not allowed. You could use a default value for the anchor text in this case:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name.initials ?? "->", "Index", new { i = item.Name.initials })
```